# Execute alert only once after a link (expander) has been clicked

Tags: jquery, alert, require-once

Hopefully someone can help with my next challenge. The following Script works in conjunction with my HTML in that when I click an expanded header it opens and closes. I also have an alert  function being called which displays the text of the expanded header. This works.

What I would like to do is make it so that the alert can only be displayed one time and any subsequent clicks to the already clicked expander header stops the alert from displaying.

Here's my Jquery code that I am working from...

```
  somesite.ca = {
        init: function() {
    $('.qa-set')
        .find('.answer')
            .addClass('hide')
            .end()
        .find('h3')
            .addClass('collapsed')
            .bind('click', this.click);
    $('#expand').bind('click', this.expandAll);
    $('#collapse').bind('click', this.collapseAll);
},

click: function(){
    $(this)
        .toggleClass('collapsed')
        .parent()
            .find('.answer')
                .slideToggle('fast');
                // Once the expander has been clicked execute alert only once for that particular expander header
                alert($(this).text());

},


}
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `alert()` in an if-statement that checks if a variable is set.

```
var expander_clicked = false;

click: function(){
$(this)
    .toggleClass('collapsed')
    .parent()
        .find('.answer')
            .slideToggle('fast');
    if (!expander_clicked) { // only alert if expander wasn't previously clicked
        alert($(this).text());
        expander_clicked = true;
    }
},
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That works well!

One small problem is that this code disables the alert for all expanders once one of them has been clicked. This might explain a bit clearly what I am trying to do (sorry if lacking proper explanation):

5 expanders on a page.

User clicks expander 1 (alert fires) then clicks expander 3 (alert fires), user clicks expander 4 (alert fires), clicks expander 1 again (no alert), and then clicks expander 3 again (no alert).

So the alert is specific to an expander. Hopefully this was clearer and I didn't waste your time. What you wrote works perfect, just too perfect :)

Comment: It seems if I add this.expander_clicked it seems to work.

$(this)
    .toggleClass('collapsed')
    .parent()
        .find('.answer')
            .slideToggle('fast');
    if (!this.expander_clicked) { 
        alert($(this).text());
        this.expander_clicked = true;
    }
},

can anyone see potential problems with how I have this structured?

Thanks again! Awesome community...